# R Reticulate: 'Unable to locate conda environment' when attempting to use_condaenv(required = TRUE)

Tags: r, reticulate

I see variations of this question have been asked but none of the answers have resolved my problem. I'm using Windows 10, R version 3.6.2, RStudio version 1.2.5033, reticulate version 1.14

```
> library(reticulate)
> library(dplyr)

> conda_list()
```

```
          name                                                                        python
1  r-miniconda                     C:\\Users\\caleb\\AppData\\Local\\r-miniconda\\python.exe
2 r-reticulate C:\\Users\\caleb\\AppData\\Local\\r-miniconda\\envs\\r-reticulate\\python.exe
```

So I try to use the second item:

```
> conda_list()[[2]][2] %>%
+   use_condaenv(required = TRUE)
```

But I get the following error:

```
Error in use_condaenv(., required = TRUE) : 
  Unable to locate conda environment 'C:/Users/caleb/AppData/Local/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/python.exe'.
```

Looking for available versions gets me:

```
> py_discover_config()
python:         C:/Users/caleb/AppData/Local/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/python.exe
libpython:      C:/Users/caleb/AppData/Local/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/python36.dll
pythonhome:     C:/Users/caleb/AppData/Local/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate
version:        3.6.10 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jan  7 2020, 15:18:16) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
Architecture:   64bit
numpy:          C:/Users/caleb/AppData/Local/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/Lib/site-packages/numpy
numpy_version:  1.18.1
```

This is my first attempt use Python from R so I'm confident this is a user-error issue but searching the error message and looking through related stack threads hasn't helped. Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `use_condaenv` function expects an environment name, not the path to the python executable. So just use

```
use_condaenv("r-reticulate")
```

rather than trying to call `use_condaenv("C:\\Users\\caleb\\AppData\\Local\\r-miniconda\\envs\\r-reticulate\\python.exe")`

Comment: This answer is incorrect. From use_condaenv the definition of condaenv is: "The conda environment to use. For use_condaenv(), this can be the name, the absolute prefix path, or the absolute path to the python binary. If the name is ambiguous, the first environment is used and a warning is issued. For use_miniconda(), the only conda installation searched is the one installed by install_miniconda()."

Answer (score 0):

As of reticulate version 1.34.0.9000 In this case, you need to explicitly pass the conda env in one of the 3 forms:

NOTE: 1 and 2 will work in older versions.

1)

```
use_condaenv(condaenv="r-reticulate")
```

2. use_condaenv(condaenv="C:\Users\caleb\AppData\Local\r-miniconda\envs\r-reticulate\")
3. 

```
use_condaenv(condaenv="C:\\Users\\caleb\\AppData\\Local\\r-miniconda\\envs\\r-reticulate\\python.exe"
```